# Konva.js How to drag images and resize with Transformer?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva

I'm trying to drag and drop these images to the stage.
but when I dropped images, I received this error. `Konva.js Konva error: Can not cache the node. Width or height of the node equals 0. Caching is skipped.`
The process that I thought of was

1. drop the image into stage
2. If it is clicked, users can resize, rotate, drag.

What should I do differently to successfully resize images?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-meitner-7gic1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you cache a shape when image is loaded.

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (image) {
    shapeRef.current.cache();
  }
}, [shapeProps, image, isSelected]);
```

Comment: Thanks It's work properly!
However, I got one more problem.
When the image is resized, the image is not fixed and moves as much as it is reduced in that direction.

Comment: It is not related to the image caching. It is because you are using offset and resetting scale back to 1 on `transformend`. You may need to create a different question for that.